# How can I paste some text into a terminal on Jupyterlab when using Firefox?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, terminal, copy-paste

I use Firefox on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate to connect to a Jupyterlab server. I opened a terminal on Jupyterlab and would like to paste some text into it. On Chrome I do  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + right-click, in the contextual menu select "paste", but on Firefox the contextual menu doesn't have the "paste" option:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can't you literally use the regular Paste shortcuts? There is Ctrl-V and there is Shift-Insert. Both of them are usable in the general context and, while the former might be disabled for a reason, the second normally isn't.

The lack of a Paste option means that no text box is present where you're right clicking.

Another option that might work is Ctrl-Shift-V. You can try it as well.

Let me know what works for you.

Comment: Thanks, Ctrl-V didn't work, but Ctrl-Shift-V did!